# Tumblr Custom Page: Injected Tags

Tags: tumblr

I'm trying to set up a custom page on my Tumblr. I want to serve a JS/JSON file, so I need a completely empty document. however Tumblr seems to be injecting some tags into the page, namely:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://assets.tumblr.com/fonts/squareserif/stylesheet.css?v=4">
<script src="http://assets.tumblr.com/assets/scripts/tumblelog.js?_v=c78ef57bd25c48e7f24a984e7ef6ceba"></script>
```

Is there a way to remove these, so I can serve a JSON or XML file uninterrupted?

Comment: AFAIK, no. We have zero control over what Tumblr inject into the page, sadly.

Comment: Ah thx, I thought as the injected tags were things like font css, maybe it was to do with a theme option/user config.

Comment: That makes sense. You would need to remove `Custom Fonts` (https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#theme-options) to stop the font css injection. Anything else, meta, javascript, we have zero control over.

Answer (score 0):

No, Tumblr injects tracking and some other tags to all pages on your blog.